# dyld: Library not loaded in Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: bioinformatics, dyld

I receive the following error message upon running **gemma** (a software used in genomics) from the MAC Terminal (My system is currently running High Sierra)

```
 dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libgsl.0.dylib
 Referenced from: /Users/sv112/Desktop/AssociationMapping/bin/gemma
 Reason: image not found
ERROR on Building GEMMA kinship matrix.
```

Installing gsl (brew install gsl) did not fix this issue.
I opened the gemma file (opens as a UNIX executable) and its contents read as follows:

```
/Users/sv112/Desktop/AssociationMapping/bin/gemma ; exit;
MGM-McCusker-iMac1:~ sv112$ /Users/sv112/Desktop/AssociationMapping/bin/gemma ; exit;
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libgsl.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/sv112/Desktop/AssociationMapping/bin/gemma
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Can someone explain how these two issues are linked and a reasonable fix?

Could it simply be an issue with having an older version of the software, or does it have something to do with Mac?